# Max value of an Arithmetic Expression using Parentheses

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, maxima-minima, dynamic-programming

I want to find the max value of the following expression using Parentheses. Symbols allowed are `+, - or *`

```
1-5+3*2-6+3
```

In the book the answer is given as `57` with the following Parentheses.

`(1 -((5+3)*(2-(6+3))))`.

There is a `-` sign before `6`. If we put the `(..)` around `6+3`, why is it still `-(6+3)`. Shouldn't it be `-(6-3)`? So that when we open the `()`, `-3` will become `+3`. I have same confusion around `-((5+3)..`

Comment: Why change the sign? You are not allowed to do that. The problem asks you to just add some parenthesis symbols. If you don't have those parenthesis $(2-6+3)=-1$. If you add them $(2-(6+3))=(2-9)=-7$

Comment: I thought that adding parenthesis means same as (2 -  1* ( 6 -3)). So when we open it, it will become 2 -6 + 3. Isn't the sign change?

Comment: You are only allowed to draw `(` and `)` symbols. Nothing else

Comment: Isn't there a Math rule that says `+` and `-` can be done in any order, but the final answer is same. https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html

Comment: gmail user. That rule about $+,-$ only works if there are no parentheses. The P of PEMDAS stands for parentheses, which must be done first.

Comment: As @coffeemath noted, you ignored the first rule in your link. You must do the operations in parentheses first, before anything else

Comment: Do I assume that, when applying parentheses, this is the original state of equation? I mean I can assume that  as if equation (2−(6+3)) is given in the question. I hope not confusing..

Comment: gmail user--- It's hard to see what you are asking in your last comment. What is it you are asking if it is "assumed"? Maybe some examples of what your confusion is would help someone answer the question of your last comment.